# How to normalize a nested reponse using normalizr

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, normalizr

I would like to normalise a nested JSON data response which I get from the API. The data response contains agents who belong to multiple shifts. The relation between the entities are many-to-many association since, A shift can many agents and an agent can belong to many shifts. So I came across this normalizr utility where I tried to normalize the date to this form so I would be able parse this easier.

I tried to normalize to this form

```
{
  entities : {
    shifts:[{...}],
    agents:[{...}]
  }
}
```

```
import { normalize, schema } from 'normalizr';
import stubData from './stubData';

const agent = new schema.Entity('agents', {});

const day_agents = new schema.Entity('day_agents', {
  agents: [agent]
});

const shift = new schema.Entity('shifts', {
  day_agents
});

const normalizedData = normalize(stubData, shift);
```

stubData:

```
"shifts": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Shift 1",
        "start_time": "9:00",
        "end_time": "5:00",
        "day_agents": {
            "10/4/2019": {
                  "leaves": 1,
                  "agents": [
            {
                          "id": 1,
                          "name": "a",
                          "email": "a@b.co",
                          "group_id": 1,
                          "Leave": false
                      },
                      {
                          "id": 2,
                          "name": "b",
                          "email": "b@b.co",
                          "group_id": 1,
                          "Leave": false
                      }
                  ]
              },
            "11/4/2019": {
                "leaves": 1,
                "agents": [{
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "c",
                        "email": "c@c.co",
                        "group_id": 2,
                        "Leave": true
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "name": "d",
                        "email": "d@d.co",
                        "group_id": 2,
                        "Leave": false
                    }
                ]
            }
    }
    }]
```

Comment: Can you share the structure of `stubData`? It looks like the schema you're passing to `normalize` needs to account for that

Comment: @PaulArmstrong I edited the question. What I had mention as the response was the stubData.